# Failed to load class when working with cloudera hadoop java training project

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using cloudera quickstart to implement an hadoop project in java:
my cloudera-quickstart version is 5.8.0
here are the error messages:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
17/04/09 14:11:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/09 14:11:36 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
17/04/09 14:11:36 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getJobSubmitter(Job.java:1291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
    at StubDriver.main(StubDriver.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

I checked my Referenced Libraries at this simple training project, in the buildpath libraries, slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar; slf4j-api1.7.5.jar; slf4j-api.jar are all included.

Answer (score 1):

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

Along with the [`slf4j-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api) jar, [`slf4j-log4j12`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) jar also should be added.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException
```

Your project is missing [`jackson-mapper-asl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl) jar.

These jars are already available as part of Hadoop libraries. Updating your project's `CLASSPATH` to include `hadoop classpath` would be the easiest fix.